# Servicestack - get metadata programmatically

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way to get the metadata of a website built using Servicestack framework programmatically? We're looking to build an app that will look for a Servicestack website hosted on 2 different environments and find out if there are any differences between them. Here are the metadata details that we expect to read from the Servicestack website in the app programmatically:

- List of all operations
- Route for each operation
- Request and Response details of each operation
- If request or response type is a complex type, breakdown of all its properties and its types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access most of ServiceStack's metadata from `Metadata` property in your AppHost which returns the [ServiceMetadata](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceMetadata.cs) class. When outside your AppHost you can access it from the `HostContext.Metadata` singleton.

A lot of the information can be accessed from OperationsMap, e.g:

```
var allServices = HostContext.Metadata.OperationsMap.Values.ToList();
```

Which will return a `List<Operation>` containing most of the metadata about a Service, e.g:

- Routes for each operation are available from the `Routes` property
- The `RequestType` and `ResponseType` returns the Request DTO Type and the known Response DTO Type

All Request DTOs are DTOs/complex types. The way to access information about each Type is to use C# Reflection methods. You can use the `Type.GetSerializableProperties()` extension method to get the serializable `PropertyInfo[]` of a `Type`.

Note you can also query a lot of this metadata in real-time using the [Metadata Debug Template](http://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#metadata-debug-template), enabled when you register the `TemplatePagesFeature` plugin:

```
Plugins.Add(new TemplatePagesFeature { 
    EnableDebugTemplate = true,       // viewable by Admin users
    //EnableDebugTemplateToAll = true // viewable by all users
})
```

Where you can query ServiceStack metadata of your Services in real-time using [ServiceStack Templates](http://templates.servicestack.net/):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, will give it a try. This is probably what I wanted.

Comment: What if I want to access the metadata of a service from another application (say console application) that only knows the URL of the servicestack site?

Comment: @Shyam If you register the [Open API feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi) you can access a Open API v2 json response from the `/openapi` endpoint. Otherwise they can call `/types/metadata.json` to get a serialized JSON response containing a lot of the service metadata info.